# GitHub organization block pining repositories

Tags: github

While using GitHub organizations for a few years – for a studying groups – I have used to pin repos in these organizations. It have been working all right.

But once in a new organization I faced with a block. I just can not save my pins (screenshot below).

Sure that this is a free organization, linked to my personal account. Role: owner. Just as it was in all other my organizations.

Any ideas why it could be possible? Thanks.

[image: can not save pin]